# Error in Retrieving Data from database with the help of PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am watching a tutorial and following along. First of all check my code

```
<body>
<header>
    ArticlePoster
</header>

<nav>       
</nav>

<aside>
    <h2>SideBar </h2>
</aside>

<section>
    <article>
        <?php
        include("connect.php");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $title = $row['post_Title'];
                    $date = $row['post_Date'];
                    $author = $row['post_Author'];
                    $image = $row['post_Image'];
                    $content = $row['post_Content'];
                                }
                            }
                            ?>      
                            <h2> <?php  echo $title; ?> </h2>
    </article>          
</section>

</body>
```

The instructor, I am following is using MYSQL and it is deprecated. In the tutorial everything works fine, without the isset() function. But my code doesn't work without it. Now the problem is with echo $title variable.

Error i am getting is "undefined variable"
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Undefined variable" where? Please tell us the line where this occurs.

Comment: you are planing to show title of each post. Then please put your <h2> tag inside the while loop. now it is out side the loop. Also please explain why you used isset($_POST['submit']) in a result displaying code..

Comment: I am completely newbie to PHP. I am watching tutorial and following along.  Instructor did not use the Isset(). His code in video is working fine. But my is not, it gives the error "undefined" $title etc. I searched on internet and found isset() tried it and now i am not getting any error. Also, I have tried what you said "Place tag inside the while loop". It gives parse error now. @AzeezKallayi

Answer (score 0):

Hope your query is giving results.Then please try this code.

```
    include("connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
         $title = $row['post_Title'];
         $date = $row['post_Date'];
         $author = $row['post_Author'];
         $image = $row['post_Image'];
         $content = $row['post_Content'];
         echo "<h2>". $title ."</h2>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. BTW, are PHP and MYSQL case sensitive? Because, issue was in 'post_title" etc fields. I have created MYSQL table rows like this 'Post_title' and when I changed small p with capital. That showed the result. Thanks a ton :) @AzeezKallayi

Comment: cool and you are welcome @Qasim Ali. if the answer helped you, you can make the answer as best answer and give vote also. so other user can also use the answer

Comment: Sorry, need 15 reputation to give vote @AzeezKallayi

Comment: I need little help. I am trying to echo an image which would be displayed along with my content. I have a folder named as images. I tried many codes but image is not displaying. Could you help me ? @AzeezKallayi
Thanks and regards,

Comment: Just show me your code for displaying image. how you stored your image in your database.is it file name?

Comment: In above mention code you can see, I have declared a variable $image. The image is stored in Database. I am trying this code to display it on browser (the folder is named as images in which photos would be saved and then would be displayed on browser)echo '<img src="'.$image.'Q.jpg " height="100" width="100" />';'Confused @AzeezKallayi

Comment: what is the value of variable  $image ?

Comment: to check i need your value of $image. what is the value of $image

Comment: Sorry my friend I couldn't get the term 'value'. I have posted all of my code. Please check it thanks and @AzeezKallayi

Comment: ok after your  echo "<h2>". $title ."</h2>"; this line please add  echo '<img src="'.$image.'" height="100" width="100" />'; and check

Comment: There are two images in images folder and named as "Q.jpg and MyName.jpg" are their names called value? @AzeezKallayi I am so thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and the other is shown above. you could check it @AzeezKallayi 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

```
    $title = $_POST['Title'];
    $date = date('y/m/d');
    $author = $_POST['Author'];
    $content = $_POST['Content'];
    $image_name = $_FILES['Image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['Image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['Image']['size'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
if( $title == '' or $author == '' or $content == '' )
{
    echo "<script>alert ('Please fill all fields')</script>";
        exit();
}

    if($image_type == "image/jpeg" or $image_type == "image/png" or $image_type == "image/gif") {

        if($image_size <=50000) {
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "images/$image_name");

        }
        else {  

            echo "<script>alert('Image should not be larger than 50kb')</script>";  
            }


    }

    else {  

            echo "<script>alert('image type is not valid')</script>";   

            }
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_Title,post_Date,post_Author,post_Image,post_content) values ('$title','$date','$author','$image_name','$content')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

        echo "<h1>Post Has been Published</h1>";

    }
}
```